# Can't deploy to Google Cloud Platform on Laravel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04, php7, laravel, google-app-engine-standard

I got the following error while deploying laravel on GCP with "gcloud app deploy".

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build ID~~~ status: FAILURE
Error ID: 5888fcc4
Error type: UNKNOWN
Error message: Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.3 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v8.2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.2.0].
    - laravel/framework v8.2.0 requires php ^7.3 -> your PHP version (7.2.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for nunomaduro/collision v5.0.2 -> satisfiable by nunomaduro/collision[v5.0.2].
    - nunomaduro/collision v5.0.2 requires php ^7.3 -> your PHP version (7.2.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - laravel/framework v8.2.0 requires php ^7.3 -> your PHP version (7.2.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/tinker v2.4.2 requires illuminate/console ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.2.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v2.4.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v2.4.2].


php -v
PHP 7.3.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2020 06:46:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.22, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I also checked the php version, but I was able to confirm that it was 7.3

I checked composer.json and it was specified in 7.3

```
 "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
            },
```

I tried "composer install", "composer update" and "composer upgrade" with reference to the information on the net, but the problem was not solved.

I checked this [site](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard) for how to deploy

Comment: The error shows 7.2.33, but
I don't have PHP 7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you double confirm what is the php version you put in your app.yaml file ?

```
runtime: php73
```

Also, [If you have a required PHP version specified in your composer.json file, you will have to remove the element for a successful deployment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#runtime_version).

Comment: When I checked the app.yaml file, it was php72!
I changed this to php73 and I was able to deploy.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider upvoting his answer :o